# How can I rotate image view during pathAnimation in android?

Tags: android, layout, path

I am first setting path through coordinates using `path.lineto()` function.

Now I am animating my image view on this final path using value animator. 
This is for above API 21

```
pathAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(monsterImage, "x", "y", path);
```

For API 11+ I used this:

```
pathAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0.0f, 1.0f);
            pathAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                float[] point = new float[2];

                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                    float val = animation.getAnimatedFraction();
                    PathMeasure pathMeasure = new PathMeasure(path, false);
                    pathMeasure.getPosTan((pathMeasure.getLength() - 1) * val, point, null);
                    monsterImage.setX(point[0]);
                    monsterImage.setY(point[1]);
                }
            });
```

But I want whenever animation changes its direction it should rotate the image. i.e. each line to rotate my image 90 degree clockwise.

How can I do this?

Comment: see `PathMeasure` class and use it in own `ObjectAnimator` implementation

Comment: @pskink I saw there is a function nextContour() which tells about the next contour. How can use that during animation?

Comment: do you have multiple contours or simple path with several lines?

Comment: @pskink I have 4-5 coordinates not in a straight line.  I want to rotate imageview 90 degrees clockwise/ anti clockwise according to the turn taken in the path.

Comment: I edit the question. I added the code of how I animating in API 11+ devices.

Comment: so use `getPosTan` and do not create `PathMeasure` inside `onAnimationUpdate` as it is called several times per second